# Questions about websocket framing

Tags: websocket

According to the RFC 6455 specification about websocket's.
Data frame structure is follows:

```
                          frame-fin           ; 1 bit in length
                          frame-rsv1          ; 1 bit in length
                          frame-rsv2          ; 1 bit in length
                          frame-rsv3          ; 1 bit in length
                          frame-opcode        ; 4 bits in length
                          frame-masked        ; 1 bit in length
                          frame-payload-length   ; either 7, 7+16,
                                                 ; or 7+64 bits in
                                                 ; length
                          [ frame-masking-key ]  ; 32 bits in length
                          frame-payload-data     ; n*8 bits in
                                                 ; length, where
                                                 ; n >= 0
```

So the minimum length of byte array to hold a frame would be 224 bytes (56 bits)? As I read on internet to represent a bit in byte array we need 4 bytes (1000).

How do I mask data? And what data should I mask? Only frame-payload-data or all the frame except the mask key?

Comment: I'm not sure what language you're coding in... but reading through source code is a great teacher. I recommend you read the source code for a parser in a language you're fluent in (I wrote [a Websocket parser in C](https://github.com/boazsegev/facil.io/blob/16d5cfe1bf5e0b10d54320c767fcaaad604b0d1c/lib/facil/http/parsers/websocket_parser.h), but there's a parser in almost any language you can think of, just pick one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `frame-masking-key` field is only present when the frame is masked, which is only done for frames sent by a client to a server.  And the `frame-payload-data` is optional; a frame may be empty, containing no data.  Therefore the minimum length of a frame in the client-to-server direction is (1+1+1+1+4+1+7+32)=48 bits or 6 bytes, and the minimum length of a frame in the server-to-client direction is (1+1+1+1+4+1+7)=16 bits or 2 bytes.

Those would be frames that carry no payload.  Obviously frames that carry payload data will require additional space.

> As I read on internet to represent a bit in byte array we need 4 bytes
> (1000).

Umm, no, each byte holds 8 bits.  It might be convenient within a program to use larger data units to represent bit values, but that is completely independent of the format that is used in the actual frame.

> How do I mask data? And what data should I mask? Only frame-payload-data
> or all the frame except the mask key?

You mask by XOR-ing the `frame-masking-key` over the `frame-payload-data`.  This is described in [section 5.3 of RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.3).